why does the wrong toast message keep appearing?
I have a class called BookRoomActivity:
public class BookRoomActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    String staffPromotionCode;
    EditText etRoomName,etprice,etDate,etCapacity,etPromotion;
    Button btnBook;
   FirebaseFirestore db;

   final boolean[]promotionCodeMatched = {false};
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_book_room);

        // Retrieve promotion code set by staff from intent
        Intent z = getIntent();
        staffPromotionCode = z.getStringExtra("Promotion");


        btnBook = findViewById(R.id.btnBook);
        etRoomName = findViewById(R.id.etRoomName);
        etprice = findViewById(R.id.etPrice);
        etDate = findViewById(R.id.etDate);
        etCapacity = findViewById(R.id.etCapacity);
        etPromotion = findViewById(R.id.etPromotion);

        db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

        Intent i = getIntent();
        Room room = (Room) i.getSerializableExtra("updatedRoom");

        if (room != null){
            etRoomName.setText(room.getRoomName());
            etPromotion.setText(room.getRoomName());
            etCapacity.setText(String.valueOf(room.getCapacity()));
            etDate.setText(String.valueOf(room.getDate()));
            etprice.setText(String.valueOf(room.getPrice()));
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(BookRoomActivity.this, "Error: Room details not found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        btnBook.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Retrieve details from EditText fields
                String roomName = etRoomName.getText().toString().trim();
                double price = Double.parseDouble(etprice.getText().toString().trim());
                int date = Integer.parseInt(etDate.getText().toString());
                int capacity = Integer.parseInt(etCapacity.getText().toString().trim());
                String promotion = etPromotion.getText().toString().trim();

                final boolean[] promotionCodeMatched = {false}; // Declare and initialize promotionCodeMatched

                // Retrieve promotion code set by staff from intent
                Intent z = getIntent();
                staffPromotionCode = z.getStringExtra("Promotion");

                // Retrieve user-entered promotion code
                String enteredPromotionCode = promotion.trim().toLowerCase();

                // Check if the entered promotion code matches the staff-set promotion code
                if (enteredPromotionCode.equals(staffPromotionCode)) {
                    promotionCodeMatched[0] = true;
                } else {
                    // Fetch the room details from Firestore
                    db.collection("rooms")
                            .whereEqualTo("roomName", roomName)
                            .get()
                            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                        for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                                            Room room = document.toObject(Room.class);
                                            String firestorePromotionCode = room.getPromotion().trim().toLowerCase();
                                            if (enteredPromotionCode.equals(firestorePromotionCode)) {
                                                promotionCodeMatched[0] = true;
                                                break;
                                            }
                                        }

                                        if (!promotionCodeMatched[0]) {
                                            Toast.makeText(BookRoomActivity.this, "Incorrect promotion code applied!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                        } else {
                                            // Promotion code matched, proceed with booking
                                            // Create Room object
                                            Room newRoom = new Room(0, date, capacity, roomName, promotion, price);

                                            // Store Room object in Firestore
                                            CollectionReference roomsCollection = db.collection("rooms");
                                            roomsCollection.add(newRoom)
                                                    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentReference>() {
                                                        @Override
                                                        public void onSuccess(DocumentReference documentReference) {
                                                            // Room booking successful
                                                            Toast.makeText(BookRoomActivity.this, "Room booked successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                                            finish(); // Finish the activity and go back to the previous activity
                                                        }
                                                    })
                                                    .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                                        @Override
                                                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                                            // Room booking failed
                                                            Toast.makeText(BookRoomActivity.this, "Failed to book room: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                        }
                                                    });
                                        }
                                    } else {
                                        // Handle query failure
                                        Toast.makeText(BookRoomActivity.this, "Failed to retrieve promotion code: " + task.getException(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                }
            }
        });;}}"

I am encountering an issue while implementing a promotion code feature. My objective is that when a user enters a promotion code, and it matches the code stored in my Firebase database, the app should return to the previous activity and display a 'Room Booked successfully' toast message. However, even when I enter the correct promotion code, the app consistently displays a 'Incorrect promotion code applied!' toast message instead. Could you help me understand why this is happening and suggest a solution?
So i have tried to check my firestore fields, and also googling and attempting to use similar solutions, but yet nothing seems to have worked and this was the best that i could find

Do you see the correct promotion code being sent to the application and used?

@tomerpacific , well when i clicked on one of the items, the field name for the promotion is the same exact one as the field name for the RoomName. For eg, here my RoomName is "purpleworld" and it also appears as the same for my promotion field

Ok so I have managed to resolve the issue here.So what i would need to remove is
 final boolean[] promotionCodeMatched = {false}; // Declare and initialize promotionCodeMatched

            // Retrieve promotion code set by staff from intent
            Intent z = getIntent();
            staffPromotionCode = z.getStringExtra("Promotion");

            // Retrieve user-entered promotion code
            String enteredPromotionCode = promotion.trim().toLowerCase();

            // Check if the entered promotion code matches the staff-set promotion code
            if (enteredPromotionCode.equals(staffPromotionCode)) {
                promotionCodeMatched[0] = true;
            } else {
                // Fetch the room details from Firestore
                db.collection("rooms")
                        .whereEqualTo("roomName", roomName)
                        .get()
                        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                    for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                                        Room room = document.toObject(Room.class);
                                        String firestorePromotionCode = room.getPromotion().trim().toLowerCase();
                                        if (enteredPromotionCode.equals(firestorePromotionCode)) {
                                            promotionCodeMatched[0] = true;
                                            break;
                                        }
                                    }

                                    if (!promotionCodeMatched[0]) {
                                        Toast.makeText(BookRoomActivity.this, "Incorrect promotion code applied!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    } else {

and then replace the entire bottom with
            FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("rooms")
                    .whereEqualTo("Promotion",promotion)
                    .get()
                    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                            if (!queryDocumentSnapshots.isEmpty()){
                                Room room = new Room(0, date, capacity, roomName, promotion, price,duration);

                                // Store Room object in Firestore
                                // Store Room object in Firestore
                                CollectionReference roomsCollection = db.collection("rooms");
                                roomsCollection.add(room)
                                        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentReference>() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onSuccess(DocumentReference documentReference) {
                                                // Room booking successful
                                                Toast.makeText(BookRoomActivity.this, "Room booked successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                finish(); // Finish the activity and go back to the previous activity
                                            }
                                        })
                                        .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                                // Room booking failed
                                                Toast.makeText(BookRoomActivity.this, "Failed to book room: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                            }
                                        });
                            }else {
                                Toast.makeText(BookRoomActivity.this, "Wrong promotion code applied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }
                    });
            // Create Room object

        }

so what the error that i had here was that my field class should be writtten as promotion and that afterwards all i needed was to do is to set the success or failure toast messages

The problem you have in your code comes from this line:
etPromotion.setText(room.getRoomName());

Instead of setting the promotion code you are setting the room name.
You should be doing:
etPromotion.setText(room.getPromotion());


hmm i have modified the error there, but yet the toast message for   "Toast.makeText(BookRoomActivity.this, "Incorrect promotion code applied!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); " still appears though. this is despite me keying in the correct promotion code

@Abzx - Have you debugged your code? Are you seeing the promotion being returned from Firebase correctly?
